# Como repetir colunas até "x" de vezes

Tags: php, html, mysql

Bom tenho uma coluna no meu banco de dados com nomes, eu escrevo ela na tela, através desse codigo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagina Inicial</title>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
;   include("connect.php");
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM materias";
    $con = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

    ?>
    <?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){
        ?>
<?php for($nomes =1; $nomes <= 9; $nomes++){?>
<div id="nomes">
        <?php echo $dado["$nomes"];?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>      
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Este é as colunas da tabela]

[image: E ele escreve isto na tela]

Comment: Gostaria de obter este resultado: http://i.imgur.com/2PNBs4s.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma dica: organize o seu código, abrir e fechar a tag PHP várias vezes pode acabar fazendo você se perder. Uma dica também é guardar em uma variável o HTML, e dar `echo` no final, ou vários `echo` durante a execução.

Sobre o problema, acredito que basta adicionar mais um `for` indo de 1 até 4, como observei na imagem junto com uma tag `<br>` pra quebrar linha.

```
<?php 
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

        for($nomes =1; $nomes <= 9; $nomes++){

            <div id="nomes">
                <?php echo $dado["$nomes"];
            </div>

        }
        <br>
   } 
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua edição, tinha me esquecido uma palavra. Ficou bacana agora.

Comment: Muito obrigado, não sabia que era possivel colocar mais de um for, e obrigado pela dica de organiza, vou fazer isto :D

Answer (score 5):

Sei que a pergunta já tem uma resposta escolhida, mas ainda assim vou voltar a responder e fazer algumas observações.

## 1º

*Porquê a estrutura da tabela está assim* ? Visto que são vários **usuarios/nomes** para diferentes usos, porque estão todos na mesma linha ?

Veja um exemplo, da tabela reformulada:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS materias (
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
INDEX(nome),
UNIQUE KEY(id),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `materias`(`id`, `nome`) VALUES (NULL, 'Bruno'), (NULL, 'Bruna'), (NULL, 'Gabriel'), (NULL, 'Gabriela'), (NULL, 'Felipe'), (NULL, 'Andre'), (NULL, 'Luiz'), (NULL, 'Gustavo'), (NULL, 'Otavio');
```

Se possível apagar a tabela atual em uso, e executar este código `SQL` no banco de dados em uso.

## 2º

*É realmente necessário executar o `looping` duas vezes* ? Veja, no exemplo que publicaste acima, tens um looping `for` dentro de um `while`. Quer dizer, cá eu não vejo qualquer necessidade de se fazer isso, ou talvez tenhas sido forçado a fazer isso devido a `estrutura` da tua tabela.

Eu cá faria algo assim:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM materias");
if($sql->num_rows > 0){
    while($linha = $sql->fetch_array()){
        print "<div id=\"nomes\">";    
        print $linha["nome"];    
        print "</div>";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($sql);    
} else {
    die("Sem resultados");    
}
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Repara que tenho um único `looping`, que faz exatamente a mesma coisa que o teu código fazia, além de ser uma boa prática é simples.

Ou ainda, desta forma:

```
...
print "<div id=\"nomes\">";    
while($linha = $sql->fetch_array()){
    print $linha["nome"] . "<br/>";      
}
print "</div>";
...
```

Que faria com que os nomes retornados ficassem numa única tag `<div>`.

Outra coisa é, se o objetivo é limitar o numero de resultados a ser processado e posteriormente exibido, porque não usar o cláusula `LIMIT` ?

Veja outro exemplo:

```
$sql = $conexao->query("SELECT * FROM materias LIMIT 4");
```

Isso significa que dos 9 nomes existentes na tabela, apenas os 4 primeiros serão selecionados, e posteriormente impressos no looping.

Espero que tenhas entendido. Boa sorte.

Comment: Entendi sim, obrigado pela ajuda, o objetivo não é limitar, mas sim repetir a coluna nome

Comment: Vê as modificações que fiz. Sim, eu cheguei até a pensar que parte do teu objetivo era limitar o número de resultados, porque na resposta abaixo o primeiro looping tinha `for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)`, e depois ainda aparecia outro looping. De qualquer das formas, podes fazer assim, que é igualmente eficaz e recomendado na maior parte das vezes.

Answer (score 0):

É simples de fazer mas tem que ter uma tabela que chama `t_vez` que contém somente campos *"nome numero"*, que tem números de 1 á 200. Então, pode observar pelo sql abaixo, que é feita uma pesquisa na tabela `t_vendas`, que tem um campo com nome `vendaquantidade`, que poderia ser quantas ficha vão ser impressas.

A pesquisa verifica se tem `vendasquantidades` maior ou igual a numero, exemplo se tiver no campo vendasquantidades o numero tres então ira repitir 3 linhas por que no campo numero da tabela vez tem numero um (menor), dois (menor) e três (igual).

```
SELECT * FROM  T_VENDAS AS A, T_VEZ AS B WHERE A.VENDAQUANTIDADE >= B.NUMERO 
  AND A.VENDANUMERO = ' + INTTOSTR(RESULTADO) + ' AND A.VENDAIMPRIMIR = "SIM" 
  ORDER BY A.VENDAQUANTIDADE, A.PRODUTONUMERO
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do site, fornecendo uma resposta melhor organizada e pontuada, sem utilizar CAPS LOCK em todo o texto.